# Is it possible to calculate atomic radius with electron configuration?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electrons, electronic-configuration, atomic-radius

I need to know whether is it possible to calculate the atomic radius according to the number of electrons and electron configuration. Or is there any way to calculate the atomic radius using common characteristics which an atom has?

Comment: You can find the effective nuclear charge ($Z^*$) using [Slater's rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater's_rules) and then plug it into Bohr's formula ($r = \dfrac{53 n^2}{Z^*} \pu{pm}$). This value is quite close to the [covalent radius](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radius#Empirically_measured_atomic_radius).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no measuring the radius of a single atom, mainly because electrons are around the nuclei: **We can't define a radius for any single atom.** Take a loom at the uncertainty principle:

> Introduced first in 1927, by the German physicist Werner Heisenberg, it states that the more precisely the position of some particle is determined, the less precisely its momentum can be known, and vice versa. The formal inequality relating the standard deviation of position $\sigma _x$ and the standard deviation of momentum $\sigma _p$ was derived by Earle Hesse Kennard later that year and by Hermann Weyl in 1928: $$\sigma _x \sigma _p \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$$ [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle)

Thus, if you want to measure an atom's radius, you have to measure the distance between two nuclei, and then divide it by two. This results in different types of radius defined for atoms. The most common are [covalent radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_radius), [ionic radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_radius), and [Van der Waals radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_radius). Radii trends are what that are mostly studied in undergrad chemistry, rather than the how of measuring them with advanced techniques.

Chemguide is pretty informative when it gets to teaching the trends:

[chemguide: atomic radius](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/atoms/properties/atradius.html)

Comment: Can you explain the "Calculated" column on the [Wikipedia data page to the atomic radii of the elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radii_of_the_elements_(data_page)). What are they calculating, and how? Obviously, judging from the empirical column, the calculated radii are WAY off on most of the elements, so their calculations were suspect, but what were they calculating?

Comment: @Jimmy The source in Wikipedia used a quantum chemical model to 'solve' the Schroedinger equation for atoms with a certain number of electrons. Simply put, they used a special method to solve a complicated equation using computers to predict how electrons behave around atoms. The error is high because the paper is from 1967. The methods used have since improved considerably to decrease that error.